# trying to add a column to a dataframe from an existing dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a new dataframe (called "averages") in r based on an already existing dataframe (named "old). "averages" has a column with all the unique values from a column in "old". Now I would like to add another column from "old" to "averages", with values from "old" that match the values associated with the unique values from the other column in "old".

What I used to make the new dataframe:

```
> averages <- data.frame(unique(old$Tree), avg) ## creating new dataframe
```

This was the code I tried to add the new column:

```
> averages <- data.frame(unique(old$Tree), avg, old$Site) ## creating new dataframe
```

And I get this error:

```
    Error in data.frame(unique(old$Tree), avg, old$Site) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 1110
```

I tried fixing the issue with this but thought it wouldn't work (it didn't):

```
> averages <- data.frame(unique(old$Tree), avg, unique(old$Site)) ## creating new dataframe

    Error in data.frame(unique(old$Tree), avg, unique(old$Site)) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 3
```

Any help on how to add this new column would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi there, the dplyr package in R has some handy (super handy!) functions inside it. One set looks like it would be useful here: the join functions (they've been implemented in a way that mimics/duplicates SQL joins). Does this help? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Comment: Because the length of `unique` elements, and 'old$Site' differ

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could do it using dplyr

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

df <- left_join(averages, old, by = c("ID_col_in_averages" = "ID_col_in_old"))
```

where if I understand correctly both ID colums to use in the join are Tree

Comment: this almost worked but not quite! it gave me every column of "old" but they all had NAs for some reason

Comment: Could you provide the results of glimpse(old) and glimpse(averages) to make sure we understand what your data is like?